# How to remove a submodule from git so that it is deleted from the file system on pull

Tags: linux, git, git-submodules, git-rm

I have a submodule named my_submodule, which I would like to delete. I need to make sure that it is removed from other developers' file systems as well, to prevent accidentally using it.

I can't require the other develpers to run any extra commands to clean the directory. The repository is worked on by a few hundred people.

I can successfully remove the submodule, which causes it to be removed from git tracking, and also deletes it locally from my file system. When other developers pull the changes, the submodule directory becomes untracked, but is not deleted.They get this error:

`warning: unable to rmdir 'path/to/my_submodule': Directory not empty`

I've tried the following strategies, which all resulted in the above error. For each strategy, the repo that I pulled to did not have any local changes.

1.

```
git rm path/to/my_submodule
git commit
```

2. 

```
git submodule deinit path/to/my_submodule
rm -rf .git/modules/path/to/my_submodule
git rm -f path/to/my_submodule
git commit -a
```

Using git version 2.25.1, on Linux.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that a simple `git pull` will delete a directory or a submodule -- for example, if said directory on target computer contains untracked or gitignored files, directory won't get deleted.

Comment: @LeGEC, the submodule is not gitignored, and my experiments were all done on clean copies of the repository with no local changes.

Comment: the pblm is the gitignore inside the submodule and/or if people has created files or directory inside the submodule, a simple empty directory inside the suibmodule will prevent the deletion

Comment: @Ôrel, see the updated question, there are no local changes in the target. The submodule does have a gitignore file (below). Could that cause this problem?

`__pycache__/
build/*
dist/*
my_submodule.egg-info/
*.pyc
.idea/*
venv/*`

Comment: @justauser you cannot know what other people has done. And yes, ignored files will prevent deletion

Comment: @Ôrel, that is true. Even when I find a way to accomplish this task, if other users for some reason have local changes to this submodule, there will still be problems. (They probably will not, as only a couple of people actually use it.)



However, in this case, the experiments were done locally on my computer, with 2 different copies of the same repository. So I know for a fact that there were no local changes, and none of the given methods worked. I would like to find a method that will work for most of the developers (who have not touched this submodule).

Comment: you can use a git hook `post-merge` to delete all the folder